# How to merge adjacent cubes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to develop a small dungeon. My idea to to generate it programmatically and refine it by hand. Floors and walls are all cubes.

This is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwJEI5lgPQBmR3hTWUd6bDFMLVU/view?usp=sharing). I want to do two things:

1. Merge Wall_1_Room04 with Wall_1_Room05
2. Merge the wall obtained in the previous step with Wall_7_Room04

I looked for a solution, but I was not able to find it. So I have a few questions for you:

- Is is possible to do it? If yes, how?
- Is the fact that every Wall has a child cube a limitation?

Comment: Do you want to that programmatically too? Or by hand?

Comment: I think about enhancing by hand the model

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is select Wall_1_Room04, then select Wall_1_Room05. once they are both selected, with Wall_1_Room05 being the active object press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. This will join the walls, the origin will be at the location of Wall_1_Room05's previous origin.

After that, tab into edit mode, select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> > Remove doubles. repeat the process for Wall_7_Room_04.

Comment: Note that it won't quite be that simple for `wall_7_room_04`, as there is no geometry to merge on the inside corner. You'll have to add a quick loopcut there first.

Comment: Thanks there, i think it worked for me though. Here's the .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32169

Comment: Look closely at the intersection at the corner, they aren't really merged.. (non-manifold geometry and intersecting faces). Also that wall isn't `wall_7_room_04` ;)

Comment: I see. if I hadn't removed doubles it would have been easier to fix. and it would be the same basic procedure for the correct wall, right?

Comment: Yep, should be.

Comment: What is a loopcut?

Comment: Use Ctrl+R to add a loopcut, basically a 'belt' of edges that goes around your object to add extra geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Join those 3 walls together, select their inner faces, delete vertices, select all, remove doubles, select all and solidify.

[Video Link](http://youtu.be/i2w39D2bDZU)

Comment: Seriously guys, stop down voting him. JuhaW, try to add more detail, even if it takes longer.

Comment: We like to have more detailed answers here, try to add detail on *how* to do things too. Links to a external video are a good bonus, but shouldn't be relied upon as the core of the answer in case the link goes away in the future.